# Access Finder Alias Icon

Tags: objective-c, macos

Finder displays icons for both `Alias` and `symlink` as a folder with a small arrow.

I currently use the following to get icon for display.

[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[item fullPath]]

This displays icons for both Alias as a folder with a small arrow but symlink as a plain folder.

I assume OSX is compositing the icon with `AliasBadgeIcon.icns`, but why does it not for symlinks.
Both show Kind as Alias.

Is there any way of getting the composite for symlinks?

I could probably construct my own with `CALayer` (which seems complex). I welcome any simpler suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable reason for the difference in behavior for aliases and symlinks is that symlinks are resolved automatically by many of the low-level (POSIX/BSD) APIs, while aliases are not. It's probably a bug in `NSWorkspace` that it gets the image of the target of the symlink rather than the symlink itself out of simple neglect to specifically avoid that.

I'm not in a position to test at the moment, but if you can target deployment to 10.10 and later, you can try using:

```
NSImage* icon;
if ([someURL getResourceValue:&icon forKey:NSURLThumbnailKey error:NULL])
    /* make use of icon */;
```

That *may* be smarter about URLs referring to symlinks.

If not, you would instead get the `NSURLIsSymbolicLinkKey` resource value (as a boolean `NSNumber`) to determine if you need to composite the two images. To composite them, create a new image that draws itself by drawing the two images in sequence:

```
NSImage* fileIcon = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[item fullPath]];
NSImage* aliasBadge = /* ... load AliasBadgeIcon.icns ... */;
NSImage* badgedFileIcon = [NSImage imageWithSize:fileIcon.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL (NSRect dstRect){
    [fileIcon drawAtPoint:dstRect.origin fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
    [aliasBadge drawAtPoint:dstRect.origin fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1];
    return YES;
}];
```

Comment: `NSURLThumbnailKey` seemed to work, but resulted in no display. I tried the 2nd suggestion but the `drawAtPoint` only applies to `NSImageRep`

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I've edited the answer to use the proper drawing method.

Comment: Thanks. This need a minor change, but works with the following addition [aliasBadge setSize:NSMakeSize(32, 32)];

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Maybe better to set its size based on the `fileIcon.size`.